# Windows Media Extender Recording

Tags: windows-media-center, htpc, media-center-extender

I intend to use a [Windows Home Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/41993/information-on-windows-home-server/42003#42003) (WHS) as a storage medium for my movies and TV programs. Obviously, I will need a machine setup to record TV programs. What I am wondering is if it possible to setup recordings from a media extender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** You can schedule recordings via a media extender. In essence the media extender is just an extension of your media center.

A media extender allows you to perform all the functions as if you were directly connected to the media center, such as record, watch, delete shows.

Keep in mind though, the media files do not reside on the media extender, but are streamed to the media extender from the media center.